# My discord bot say in terminal: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have question why my code when i send command on chat !lek (drug) [name of the drug] in terminal say: invalid syntax (, line 1). I don't know what to do.

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json
import tweepy
import os

# Pobierz aktualny katalog, w którym znajduje się skrypt
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Klucz API Twittera
twitter_consumer_key = "00000"
twitter_consumer_secret = "000000000000"
twitter_access_token = "00000000000000000"
twitter_access_token_secret = "000000000000000"

# Klucz API News API
news_api_key = "98166982a7e4455da7f8f65b95ed50a7"

# Lista specjalistycznych źródeł informacji medycznych
medical_sources = [
    'medical-news-today.com',
    'sciencedaily.com',
    'medscape.com',
    'bmj.com',
    'nejm.org',
    'fda.gov',  # Dodaj przecinek, aby oddzielić od poprzedniego elementu
    'cdc.gov'
]

# Konfiguracja Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_consumer_key, twitter_consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_access_token, twitter_access_token_secret)
twitter_api = tweepy.API(auth)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# ID kanału, na którym ma działać bot
wybrany_kanal_id = 1172578358589145119

async def send_embed_segments(ctx, embed):
    # Maksymalna długość wiadomości to 2000 znaków, dzielimy embed, jeśli jest zbyt długi
    embed_str = str(embed)
    max_length = 2000

    for i in range(0, len(embed_str), max_length):
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed.from_dict(eval(embed_str[i:i + max_length])))

@bot.command()
async def lek(ctx, *, nazwa_leku):
    try:
        # Sprawdzanie, czy komenda została wywołana na odpowiednim kanale
        if ctx.channel.id != wybrany_kanal_id:
            await ctx.send('Ta komenda może być używana tylko na określonym kanale.')
            return

        # Lista plików JSON do przetworzenia
        lista_plikow = [
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0001-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0002-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0003-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0004-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0005-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0006-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0007-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0008-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0009-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0010-of-0011.json'),
            os.path.join(current_directory, 'drug-label-0011-of-0011.json')
        ]

        # Inicjalizacja pierwszego wyniku jako None
        pierwszy_wynik = None

        # Przetwarzanie każdego pliku z listy
        for nazwa_pliku in lista_plikow:
            with open(nazwa_pliku, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                data = json.load(file)

            found_results = [result for result in data.get('results', []) if nazwa_leku.lower() in result.get('openfda', {}).get('brand_name', [''])[0].lower()]

            # Sprawdź, czy znaleziono wynik
            if found_results:
                pierwszy_wynik = found_results[0]
                break  # Jeśli znaleziono w jednym pliku, nie trzeba dalej szukać

        if pierwszy_wynik:
            nazwa_handlowa = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('brand_name', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            opis = pierwszy_wynik.get('purpose', ['Brak informacji'])[0]

            # Dodatkowe pola
            producent = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('manufacturer_name', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            nazwa_generyczna = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('generic_name', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            ndc = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('product_ndc', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            typ_produktu = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('product_type', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            droga_podawania = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('route', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            substancja = pierwszy_wynik.get('openfda', {}).get('substance_name', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            cel = pierwszy_wynik.get('purpose', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            wskazania_i_uzytkowanie = pierwszy_wynik.get('indications_and_usage', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            ostrzezenia = pierwszy_wynik.get('warnings', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            zachowaj_poza_zasiegiem_dzieci = pierwszy_wynik.get('keep_out_of_reach_of_children', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            dawkowanie_i_podawanie = pierwszy_wynik.get('dosage_and_administration', ['Brak informacji'])[0]
            przechowywanie_i_obsluga = pierwszy_wynik.get('storage_and_handling', ['Brak informacji'])[0]

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Informacje o leku: {nazwa_leku}', color=0x00ff00)
            embed.add_field(name='Nazwa handlowa', value=nazwa_handlowa, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Opis', value=opis, inline=False)

            # Dodatkowe pola
            embed.add_field(name='Producent', value=producent, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Nazwa generyczna', value=nazwa_generyczna, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Numer NDC', value=ndc, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Typ produktu', value=typ_produktu, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Droga podawania', value=droga_podawania, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Substancja', value=substancja, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Cel', value=cel, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Wskazania i użycie', value=wskazania_i_uzytkowanie, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Ostrzeżenia', value=ostrzezenia, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Zachowaj poza zasięgiem dzieci', value=zachowaj_poza_zasiegiem_dzieci, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Dawkowanie i podawanie', value=dawkowanie_i_podawanie, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Przechowywanie i obsługa', value=przechowywanie_i_obsluga, inline=False)

            await send_embed_segments(ctx, embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Nie znaleziono informacji o leku o nazwie "{nazwa_leku}".')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send('Wystąpił błąd podczas wczytywania informacji o leku z pliku.')

@bot.command()
async def aktualnosci(ctx):
    try:
        # Pobieranie aktualności medycznych z News API
        sources = ','.join(medical_sources)
        url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources={sources}&apiKey={news_api_key}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        news_data = response.json()

        if 'articles' in news_data:
            articles = news_data['articles']
            for article in articles[:5]:  # Wyświetl pierwsze 5 artykułów
                title = article.get('title', 'Brak tytułu')
                description = article.get('description', 'Brak opisu')
                url = article.get('url', '#')

                embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, url=url, color=0x0000ff)
                await send_embed_segments(ctx, embed)

        else:
            await ctx.send('Nie udało się pobrać aktualności.')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send('Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania aktualności.')

@bot.command()
async def get_tweets(ctx, username, count=5):
    try:
        tweets = twitter_api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=count, tweet_mode="extended")

        for tweet in tweets:
            tweet_text = tweet.full_text
            tweet_url = f"https://twitter.com/{username}/status/{tweet.id}"

            # Sprawdź, do którego kanału Discorda wysłać tweet
            if username.lower() == 'cdcgov':
                channel_id = 1172578344911519774
            elif username.lower() == 'fda':
                channel_id = 1172578358589145119
            else:
                channel_id = None

            if channel_id:
                channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
                await channel.send(f'Tweet od @{username}:\n{tweet_text}\nWięcej na: {tweet_url}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania tweetów: {e}')
        await ctx.send(f'Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania tweetów: {e}')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Zalogowano jako {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        print(f'Błąd podczas przetwarzania komendy: {error.original}')  # Dodaj tę linię
        await ctx.send('Wystąpił błąd podczas przetwarzania komendy.')

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Nieprawidłowa komenda.')

bot.run('...')
```

I want my bot to send to chat "embed" divided several parts due to the fact that it does not fit and sends me an error: "In embeds: embed size exceeds maximum size of 6000".

Comment: Don't use `try/except` when you're debugging, since you don't see the full traceback and can't tell where the error is happening.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe first run without `try/except` to see full error messages. `Discord` may catch errors to run without stops and you may need to set [logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) to see all errors.

Comment: maybe problem is not chat command but you have some typo in code. We can't run code and see full error message, and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments) as text (not images)